# Floating point benchmark?

Tags: benchmarks

I've found nbench which runs on Linux but it doesn't generate a measurement in terms of flops (i.e. floating point operations per second). I've also found sysbench, but that doesn't provide floating point measurement.

Is there a recent benchmark that allows for measurement of floating point operations? Single and multi-threaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Linpack! Run `xlinpack_xeon64` in the /benchmarks/linpack directory of [this archive](http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/2169/l_lpk_p_10.3.4.007.tgz)!